How can I use Android Java interfaces in Frida JavaScript code?
I've been grinding my teeth over implementing Android Stackwalker with Frida. Getting a StackWalker instance is easy and I can call any basic method pretty easily, but, when it comes to the Java forEach method, I need to pass a function implementing the Java Consumer interface, but I don't really know how to generate one because writing one in JavaScript will not be accepted by the Java method.
var StackWalker = Java.use('java.lang.StackWalker');
var walker = StackWalker.getInstance();
var Consumer = Java.use('java.util.function.Consumer');
function cons(frame) {
    send({ id: "Ok", message : "blablabla" })
};               // <- How to implement Consumer interface ?
walker.forEach(cons);

I tried changing the implementation of the forEach method but then I can't get the inherent variables aka the stackframes

I would have expected that you need to create a new class using Java.registerClass that implements the Consumer interface.

See example here https://github.com/frida/frida-java-bridge/issues/124#issuecomment-511762870
